# How to execute PostgreSQL RAISE command dynamically

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

How to raise error from PostgreSQL SQL statement if some condition is met?
I tried code below but got error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "exec"(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$ 
    BEGIN 
      EXECUTE $1; 
      RETURN $1; 
    END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

-- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "raise"
-- LINE 1: raise 'test' 

SELECT exec('raise ''test'' ') WHERE TRUE
```

In real application `TRUE` is replaced by some condition.

**Update**

I tried to extend answer to pass exception message parameters.
Tried code below but got syntax error.
How to pass message parameters ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exec(text, variadic ) 
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$BODY$  
BEGIN  
   RAISE EXCEPTION  $1, $2;  
END;  
$BODY$; 

SELECT exec('Exception Param1=% Param2=%', 'param1', 2 );
```

Comment: Repost of PostgreSQL mailing list message http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/9E0A5B8931B849A4844AE348C4A0CC34@dell2 . Andrus, please don't post in both places without saying you've done so. Link to the SO article when posting to the Pg list.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You cannot call `RAISE` dynamically (with `EXECUTE`) in PL/pgSQL - that only works for SQL statements, and [`RAISE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) is a PL/pgSQL command.

Use this simple function instead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_raise(text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RAISE EXCEPTION '%', $1;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_raise('My message is empty!');
```

Related:

- [Generate an exception with a Context](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7598/3684)

#### Additional answer to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916838/how-to-execute-postgresql-raise-command-dynamically/11918424#comment15872969_11918424)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_raise1(VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN 
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Reading % % %!', $1[1], $1[2], $1[3];
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_raise1('the','manual','educates');
```

- `VARIADIC` is not a data type, but an [argument mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).
- Elements have to be handled like any other array element.
- To use multiple variables in a `RAISE` statement, put multiple `%` into the message text.

The above example will fail if no `$3` is passed. You'd have to assemble a string from the variable number of input elements. Example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_raise2(VARIADIC _arr text[]) 
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$func$  
DECLARE
   _msg text := array_to_string(_arr, ' and ');  -- simple string construction
BEGIN  
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Reading %!', _msg;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_raise2('the','manual','educates');
```

I doubt you need a `VARIADIC` parameter for this at all. Read [the manual here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916838/how-to-execute-postgresql-raise-command-dynamically/11918424#comment15872969_11918424).
Instead, define all parameters, maybe add defaults:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_raise3(_param1 text = ''
                                  , _param2 text = ''
                                  , _param3 text = 'educates')
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Reading % % %!', $1, $2, $3;
END 
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_raise3('the','manual','educates');
```

Or:

```
SELECT f_raise3();  -- defaults kick in
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. How to pass parameters to message also? I updated question.