# Check to see if starttime > end time of same group

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a database which has a calendar in it. Depending on which group i am trying to insert it should check if the `NEW` starttime is later then the old starttime of the group.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_rooster_tijd() returns trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
    SELECT max(eindtijd) FROM rooster WHERE rooster.groep = NEW.groep;
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$

CREATE trigger check_rooster_tijd_trigger BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON rooster
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_rooster_tijd();
```

However this does not work.

How can i fix this so that my sql checks to see if the times are later then he end times of the same group.

```
CREATE TABLE rooster(
groep               VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL
,startdatum         DATE            NOT NULL
,starttijd          TIME            NOT NULL
,einddatum          DATE            NOT NULL
,eindtijd           TIME            NOT NULL
,docent             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
,lokaal             VARCHAR(6)      NOT NULL
,check (starttijd < eindtijd)
```

---

**EDIT**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_rooster_tijd() returns trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    if(SELECT max(eindtijd) from rooster) > new.starttijd THEN
        insert into rooster values (new.groep, new.startdatum, new.starttijd, new.einddatum, new.eindtijd, new.docent, new.lokaal);
        return new;
    END IF;
    RAISE exception 'error %', new;
    return null;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

CREATE trigger check_rooster_tijd_trigger BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON rooster
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_rooster_tijd();
```

Comment: And BTW: It's good practice to use english in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your select:

```
SELECT max(eindtijd) FROM rooster WHERE rooster.groep = NEW.groep;
```

into if (as a condition) and if condition is not satisfied raise exception.

For instance (syntax may be incorrect but to give you idea):

```
if (SELECT max(eindtijd) FROM rooster WHERE rooster.groep = NEW.groep)>new.starttijd then
    raise exception 'Incorrect end time!'; 
end;
```

You can see:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html 
for more info about raising exceptions and

[How to execute PostgreSQL RAISE command dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916838/how-to-execute-postgresql-raise-command-dynamically) for examples.

Comment: i edited my question based on what you said however it gives me a stack overflow with this: PL/pgSQL function check_rooster_tijd() line 4 at SQL statement
SQL statement "insert into rooster values (new.groep, new.startdatum, new.starttijd, new.einddatum, new.eindtijd, new.docent, new.lokaal)"
PL/pgSQL function check_rooster_tijd() line 4 at SQL statement

Comment: Delete `insert into rooster values (new.groep, new.startdatum, new.starttijd, new.einddatum, new.eindtijd, new.docent, new.lokaal);` from `if` section. You don't need it - trigger is already running inside `insert` or `update`.